# Activity Monitor not showing stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server

This is SQL Server 2008 R2 running in Hyper-V virtual machine with 4 virtual cores.

Task Manager is reporting sqlservr.exe to use at least 50% CPU, sometimes 100% for minutes. I/O is very low. The top "Recent expensive queries" listed in Activity Monitor are reported in the range of 100 ms/s and pretty low figures for Logical Reads/s as well. Number of threads seems okay (around 180 for around 120 open connections, very few of them running).

Maintenance Plans are running normally: log backups every 15min, running only for a few seconds.

Any idea what could cause this high CPU load?

**Update**: It seems like I found the issue by analyzing a short unfiltered SQL trace. A stored procedure, repeatedly called by a background service, issued a SELECT statement suffering a typical "parameter sniffing" problem. After fixing this, CPU usage came down.

So I want to rephrase the question a bit: Is it normal, that stored procedures or the statements executed by stored procedures never show up in "Recent Expensive Queries"?

Comment: i don't really know but do you have the latest Service Pack installed? SP3  was released 9/26/2014 für MSSQL08R2. Maybe this helps you. I had a similar problem years ago and after installing an missing SP the problem was gone...

Comment: Good hint. I'm still running SP2 with the latest security patches. I have another production SQL Server running, same version and very similar environment/setup, not showing this behavior, though. I will try to get a maintenance window for upgrading.

Comment: Capture the summation of cpu_time in sys.dm_exec_sessions, wait for 5-10 seconds and sum it again. Check the difference. If you're seeing a good amount of cpu usage then start investigating the queries. Just because there isn't 1 individual high cost query doesn't mean you aren't getting death from a thousand small queries being executed hundreds or thousands of times.

Comment: @SeanGallardy, hm, not sure how you meant that. `select sum(cpu_time) from sys.dm_exec_sessions` will increase and also decrease over time, since sessions also stop or get resetted all the time, so repeating and comparing this query didn't give me any useful information, at least in my case.

Comment: @markus In that case use sys.dm_exec_query_stats and the total_worker_time column.

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to rephrase the question a bit: Is it normal, that stored
>   procedures or the statements executed by stored procedures never show
>   up in "Recent Expensive Queries"?

Chances are those statements where in there (at least if it was above certain metrics [See Below]) but the tool will show the statement only. It's up to the administrator to figure out the rest. It's a very minimal tool (activity monitor) that can be used to *quickly* glance and see how things are. Personally, I don't use it due to the minimalistic nature, though it is helpful when just wanting to spot check quickly.

To more address your question, there is a chance that the statements weren't in the "Recent Expensive Queries" section. Why? Below is the code used by SSMS to determine the information, as you can see there are hard coded values to what is a random guess at "expensive".

```
CREATE PROC #am_get_querystats AS 
BEGIN
-- Set @N to the number of queries to capture by each ordering metric.  Since there are seven different metrics, 
-- if N=10, you will get a minimum of 10 query plans (if the top 20 are the same for all metrics) and a max of 70
-- queries (if the five sets of 10 queries are all disjoint sets).  Actually, the query returns 'plan fingerprint' 
-- stats, not plan stats. 
DECLARE @N int;
SET @N = 20;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Step 1: Capture a snapshot of (cumulative) query stats and store it in #temp_fingerprint_stats 
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#temp_fingerprint_stats') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #temp_fingerprint_stats;
END;

-- Get timestamp of current snapshot
DECLARE @current_collection_time datetime;
SET @current_collection_time = GETDATE();

-- This CTE returns a unified view of the query stats for both in-progress queries (from sys.dm_exec_requests)
-- and completed queries (from sys.dm_exec_query_stats). 
WITH merged_query_stats AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [sql_handle], 
        statement_start_offset,
        statement_end_offset,
        plan_generation_num,
        [plan_handle], 
        query_hash AS query_fingerprint, 
        query_plan_hash AS plan_fingerprint, 
        creation_time,
        last_execution_time, 
        execution_count,
        total_worker_time / 1000 AS total_worker_time_ms,
        min_worker_time / 1000 AS min_worker_time_ms,
        max_worker_time / 1000 AS max_worker_time_ms,
        total_physical_reads,
        min_physical_reads,
        max_physical_reads,
        total_logical_writes,
        min_logical_writes,
        max_logical_writes,
        total_logical_reads,
        min_logical_reads,
        max_logical_reads,
        total_clr_time,
        min_clr_time,
        max_clr_time,
        total_elapsed_time / 1000 AS total_elapsed_time_ms,
        min_elapsed_time / 1000 AS min_elapsed_time_ms,
        max_elapsed_time / 1000 AS max_elapsed_time_ms, 
        total_elapsed_time / 1000 AS total_completed_execution_time_ms
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS q
    -- To reduce the number of rows that we have to deal with in later queries, filter out any very old rows
    WHERE q.last_execution_time > DATEADD (hour, -4, GETDATE())

    -- The UNIONed query below is a workaround for VSTS #91422, sys.dm_exec_query_stats does not reflect stats for in-progress queries. 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        [sql_handle],
        statement_start_offset,
        statement_end_offset,
        NULL AS plan_generation_num,
        plan_handle,
        query_hash AS query_fingerprint, 
        query_plan_hash AS plan_fingerprint, 
        start_time AS creation_time,
        start_time AS last_execution_time,
        0 AS execution_count,
        cpu_time AS total_worker_time_ms,
        NULL AS min_worker_time_ms,  -- min should not be influenced by in-progress queries
        cpu_time AS max_worker_time_ms,
        reads AS total_physical_reads,
        NULL AS min_physical_reads,  -- min should not be influenced by in-progress queries
        reads AS max_physical_reads,
        writes AS total_logical_writes,
        NULL AS min_logical_writes,  -- min should not be influenced by in-progress queries
        writes AS max_logical_writes,
        logical_reads AS total_logical_reads,
        NULL AS min_logical_reads,   -- min should not be influenced by in-progress queries
        logical_reads AS max_logical_reads,
        NULL AS total_clr_time,      -- CLR time is not available in dm_exec_requests
        NULL AS min_clr_time,        -- CLR time is not available in dm_exec_requests
        NULL AS max_clr_time,        -- CLR time is not available in dm_exec_requests
        total_elapsed_time AS total_elapsed_time_ms,
        NULL AS min_elapsed_time_ms, -- min should not be influenced by in-progress queries
        total_elapsed_time AS max_elapsed_time_ms, 
        NULL AS total_completed_execution_time_ms
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r 
    WHERE [sql_handle] IS NOT NULL 
        -- Don't attempt to collect stats for very brief in-progress requests; the active statement 
        -- will likely have changed by the time that we harvest query text, in the next query 
        AND DATEDIFF (second, r.start_time, @current_collection_time) > 1
)
-- Insert the fingerprint stats into a temp table.  SQL isn't always able to produce a good estimate of the amount of 
-- memory that the upcoming sorts (for ROW_NUMER()) will need because of lack of accurate stats on DMVs.  Staging the 
-- data in a temp table allows the memory cost of the sort operations to be more accurate, which avoids unnecessary 
-- spilling to tempdb. 
SELECT 
    fingerprint_stats.*, 
    example_plan.sample_sql_handle, 
    example_plan.sample_plan_handle, 
    example_plan.sample_statement_start_offset, 
    example_plan.sample_statement_end_offset
INTO #temp_fingerprint_stats
FROM
-- Calculate plan fingerprint stats by grouping the query stats by plan fingerprint
(
    SELECT 
        mqs.query_fingerprint, 
        mqs.plan_fingerprint, 
        -- The same plan could be returned by both dm_exec_query_stats and dm_exec_requests -- count distinct plan 
        -- handles only
        COUNT(DISTINCT plan_handle) AS plan_count, 
        MIN (mqs.creation_time) AS creation_time, 
        MAX (mqs.last_execution_time) AS last_execution_time, 
        SUM (mqs.execution_count) AS execution_count, 
        SUM (mqs.total_worker_time_ms) AS total_worker_time_ms, 
        MIN (mqs.min_worker_time_ms) AS min_worker_time_ms, 
        MAX (mqs.max_worker_time_ms) AS max_worker_time_ms, 
        SUM (mqs.total_physical_reads) AS total_physical_reads, 
        MIN (mqs.min_physical_reads) AS min_physical_reads, 
        MAX (mqs.max_physical_reads) AS max_physical_reads, 
        SUM (mqs.total_logical_writes) AS total_logical_writes, 
        MIN (mqs.min_logical_writes) AS min_logical_writes, 
        MAX (mqs.max_logical_writes) AS max_logical_writes, 
        SUM (mqs.total_logical_reads) AS total_logical_reads, 
        MIN (mqs.min_logical_reads) AS min_logical_reads, 
        MAX (mqs.max_logical_reads) AS max_logical_reads, 
        SUM (mqs.total_clr_time) AS total_clr_time, 
        MIN (mqs.min_clr_time) AS min_clr_time, 
        MAX (mqs.max_clr_time) AS max_clr_time, 
        SUM (mqs.total_elapsed_time_ms) AS total_elapsed_time_ms, 
        MIN (mqs.min_elapsed_time_ms) AS min_elapsed_time_ms, 
        MAX (mqs.max_elapsed_time_ms) AS max_elapsed_time_ms, 
        SUM (mqs.total_completed_execution_time_ms) AS total_completed_execution_time_ms 
    FROM merged_query_stats AS mqs
    GROUP BY 
        mqs.query_fingerprint, 
        mqs.plan_fingerprint
) AS fingerprint_stats
INNER JOIN 
(
    -- This query assigns a unique row identifier to each plan that has the same fingerprint -- we'll 
    -- select each fingerprint's 'Plan #1' (the earliest example that's still in cache) to use as a sample plan
    -- for the fingerprint.  Later (in the outer query's WHERE clause) we'll filter out all but the first plan, 
    -- and use that one to get a valid sql_handle/plan_handle. 
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY plan_fingerprint 
            ORDER BY creation_time 
        ) AS plan_instance_number 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            query_hash AS query_fingerprint, 
            query_plan_hash AS plan_fingerprint, 
            qs.[sql_handle] AS sample_sql_handle, 
            qs.plan_handle AS sample_plan_handle, 
            qs.statement_start_offset AS sample_statement_start_offset, 
            qs.statement_end_offset AS sample_statement_end_offset, 
            qs.creation_time 
        FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs 
        -- To get a sample plan for in-progress queries, we need to look in dm_exec_requests, too
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            query_hash AS query_fingerprint, 
            query_plan_hash AS plan_fingerprint, 
            r.[sql_handle] AS sample_sql_handle, 
            r.plan_handle AS sample_plan_handle, 
            r.statement_start_offset AS sample_statement_start_offset, 
            r.statement_end_offset AS sample_statement_end_offset, 
            r.start_time AS creation_time
        FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
    ) AS all_plans_numbered
) AS example_plan 
    ON example_plan.query_fingerprint = fingerprint_stats.query_fingerprint 
        AND example_plan.plan_fingerprint = fingerprint_stats.plan_fingerprint 
-- To improve perf of the next query, filter out plan fingerprints that aren't very interesting according to any of our 
-- perf metrics.  Note that our most frequent allowed execution rate for this script is one execution every 15 seconds, 
-- so, for example, a plan that is executed 50 times in a 15+ second time interval will qualify for further processing. 
WHERE plan_instance_number = 1
    AND (fingerprint_stats.total_worker_time_ms > 500       -- 500 ms cumulative CPU time
    OR fingerprint_stats.execution_count > 50               -- 50 executions
    OR fingerprint_stats.total_physical_reads > 50          -- 50 cumulative physical reads
    OR fingerprint_stats.total_logical_reads > 5000         -- 5,000 cumulative logical reads
    OR fingerprint_stats.total_logical_writes > 50          -- 50 cumulative logical writes
    OR fingerprint_stats.total_elapsed_time_ms > 5000)      -- 5 seconds cumulative execution time
-- SQL doesn't always have good stats on DMVs, and as a result it may select a loop join-based plan w/the 
-- sys.dm_exec_query_stats DMV as the inner table.  The DMVs don't have indexes that would support efficient 
-- loop joins, and will commonly have a large enough number of rows that unindexed loop joins will be an  
-- unattractive option. Given this, we gain much better worst-case perf with minimal cost to best-case perf 
-- by prohibiting loop joins via this hint. 
OPTION (HASH JOIN, MERGE JOIN);


-- Step 2: Rank the plan fingerprints by CPU use, execution count, etc and store the results in #am_fingerprint_stats_snapshots 
-- Now we have the stats for all plan fingerprints.  Return only the top N by each of our perf metrics.  
-- The reason we need a derived table here is because SQL disallows the direct use of ROW_NUMBER() 
-- in a WHERE clause, yet we need to filter based on the row number (rank). 
INSERT INTO #am_fingerprint_stats_snapshots
SELECT 
    @current_collection_time AS collection_time, 
    ranked_fingerprint_stats.*, 
    batch_text.text AS batch_text,
    plan_info.dbname
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        -- Rank the fingerprints by each of our perf metrics 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY plan_count DESC) AS plan_count_rank, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY total_worker_time_ms DESC) AS cpu_rank, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY total_physical_reads DESC) AS physical_reads_rank, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY total_logical_reads DESC) AS logical_reads_rank, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY total_logical_writes DESC) AS logical_writes_rank, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY max_elapsed_time_ms DESC) AS max_duration_rank, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY execution_count DESC) AS execution_count_rank
    FROM #temp_fingerprint_stats
) AS ranked_fingerprint_stats
-- Get the query text
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sample_sql_handle) AS batch_text
OUTER APPLY (SELECT DB_NAME(CONVERT(int, value)) AS dbname FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(sample_plan_handle) WHERE attribute='dbid') AS plan_info
WHERE 
    cpu_rank <= @N 
    OR logical_writes_rank <= @N 
    OR physical_reads_rank <= @N 
    OR max_duration_rank <= @N 
    OR execution_count_rank <= @N 
    OR plan_count_rank <= @N;


-- Step 3: Calculate the delta since the prior snapshot, and return the fingerprint stats for the just-completed time interval
-- Get timestamp of previous snapshot
DECLARE @previous_collection_time datetime;
SELECT TOP 1 @previous_collection_time = collection_time 
FROM #am_fingerprint_stats_snapshots
WHERE collection_time < @current_collection_time
ORDER BY collection_time DESC;

-- Subtract prior stats from current stats to get stats for this time interval
-- 
-- In this query, the expression below represents 'interval duration'.  If we do find the plan in the prior snapshot, we use 
-- [current_snapshot_time - prior_snapshot_time] to calculate the interval duration.  If we don't find the plan fingerprint in 
-- the prior snapshot (either because this is the first snapshot, or because this is the first time this plan has shown up in 
-- our TOP N), and if the plan has been around since before our prior snapshot, we amortize its execution cost over the plan 
-- lifetime.  
-- 
--  DATEDIFF (second, 
--      CASE 
--          WHEN (prev_stats.plan_fingerprint IS NULL AND cur_stats.creation_time < @previous_collection_time)
--              THEN cur_stats.creation_time 
--          ELSE @previous_collection_time 
--      END, 
--      @current_collection_time)
--
-- The purpose of this is to avoid the assumption that all execution stats for a 'new' query plan occurred within the just-
-- completed time interval.  It also allows us to show some execution stats immediately after the first snapshot, rather than 
-- waiting until the second snapshot. 
WITH interval_fingerprint_stats AS
(
    SELECT 
        cur_stats.batch_text, 
        SUBSTRING (
            cur_stats.batch_text, 
            (cur_stats.sample_statement_start_offset/2) + 1, 
            (
                (
                    CASE cur_stats.sample_statement_end_offset 
                        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(cur_stats.batch_text)
                        WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(cur_stats.batch_text)
                        ELSE cur_stats.sample_statement_end_offset 
                    END 
                    - cur_stats.sample_statement_start_offset
                )/2
            ) + 1
        ) AS statement_text, 
        -- If we don't have a prior snapshot, and if the plan has been around since before the start of the interval, 
        -- amortize the cost of the query over its lifetime so that we don't make the (typically incorrect) assumption 
        -- that the cost was all accumulated within the just-completed interval. 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF (second, CASE WHEN (@previous_collection_time IS NULL) OR (prev_stats.plan_fingerprint IS NULL AND cur_stats.creation_time < @previous_collection_time) THEN cur_stats.creation_time ELSE @previous_collection_time END, @current_collection_time) > 0
            THEN DATEDIFF (second, CASE WHEN (@previous_collection_time IS NULL) OR (prev_stats.plan_fingerprint IS NULL AND cur_stats.creation_time < @previous_collection_time) THEN cur_stats.creation_time ELSE @previous_collection_time END, @current_collection_time)
            ELSE 1 -- protect from divide by zero
        END AS interval_duration_sec, 
        cur_stats.query_fingerprint, 
        cur_stats.plan_fingerprint, 
        cur_stats.sample_sql_handle, 
        cur_stats.sample_plan_handle, 
        cur_stats.sample_statement_start_offset, 
        cur_stats.sample_statement_end_offset, 
        cur_stats.plan_count, 
        -- If a plan is removed from cache, then reinserted, it is possible for it to seem to have negative cost.  The 
        -- CASE statements below handle this scenario. 
        CASE WHEN (cur_stats.execution_count - ISNULL (prev_stats.execution_count, 0)) < 0 
            THEN cur_stats.execution_count 
            ELSE (cur_stats.execution_count - ISNULL (prev_stats.execution_count, 0)) 
        END AS interval_executions, 
        cur_stats.execution_count AS total_executions, 
        CASE WHEN (cur_stats.total_worker_time_ms - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_worker_time_ms, 0)) < 0 
            THEN cur_stats.total_worker_time_ms
            ELSE (cur_stats.total_worker_time_ms - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_worker_time_ms, 0)) 
        END AS interval_cpu_ms, 
        CASE WHEN (cur_stats.total_physical_reads - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_physical_reads, 0)) < 0 
            THEN cur_stats.total_physical_reads
            ELSE (cur_stats.total_physical_reads - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_physical_reads, 0)) 
        END AS interval_physical_reads, 
        CASE WHEN (cur_stats.total_logical_writes - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_logical_writes, 0)) < 0 
            THEN cur_stats.total_logical_writes 
            ELSE (cur_stats.total_logical_writes - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_logical_writes, 0)) 
        END AS interval_logical_writes, 
        CASE WHEN (cur_stats.total_logical_reads - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_logical_reads, 0)) < 0 
            THEN cur_stats.total_logical_reads 
            ELSE (cur_stats.total_logical_reads - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_logical_reads, 0)) 
        END AS interval_logical_reads, 
        CASE WHEN (cur_stats.total_elapsed_time_ms - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_elapsed_time_ms, 0)) < 0 
            THEN cur_stats.total_elapsed_time_ms 
            ELSE (cur_stats.total_elapsed_time_ms - ISNULL (prev_stats.total_elapsed_time_ms, 0)) 
        END AS interval_elapsed_time_ms, 
        cur_stats.total_completed_execution_time_ms AS total_completed_execution_time_ms,
        cur_stats.dbname
    FROM #am_fingerprint_stats_snapshots AS cur_stats
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #am_fingerprint_stats_snapshots AS prev_stats
        ON prev_stats.collection_time = @previous_collection_time
        AND prev_stats.plan_fingerprint = cur_stats.plan_fingerprint AND prev_stats.query_fingerprint = cur_stats.query_fingerprint
    WHERE cur_stats.collection_time = @current_collection_time
)
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING (statement_text, 1, 200) AS [Query], 
    /* Begin hidden grid columns */
    statement_text, 
    -- We must convert these to a hex string representation because they will be stored in a DataGridView, which can't  
    -- handle binary cell values (assumes anything binary is an image) 
    master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(query_fingerprint) AS query_fingerprint, 
    master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(plan_fingerprint) AS plan_fingerprint,     
    master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(sample_sql_handle) AS sample_sql_handle,   
    master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(sample_plan_handle) AS sample_plan_handle, 
    sample_statement_start_offset,
    sample_statement_end_offset,  
    /* End hidden grid columns */
    interval_executions * 60 / interval_duration_sec AS [Executions/min], 
    interval_cpu_ms / interval_duration_sec AS [CPU (ms/sec)], 
    interval_physical_reads / interval_duration_sec AS [Physical Reads/sec], 
    interval_logical_writes / interval_duration_sec AS [Logical Writes/sec], 
    interval_logical_reads / interval_duration_sec AS [Logical Reads/sec], 
    CASE total_executions 
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        ELSE total_completed_execution_time_ms / total_executions 
    END AS [Average Duration (ms)], 
    plan_count AS [Plan Count], 
    dbname AS [Database Name]
FROM interval_fingerprint_stats;

-- Step 4: Delete all but the most recent snapshot; we no longer need any older data
DELETE FROM #am_fingerprint_stats_snapshots
WHERE collection_time != @current_collection_time; 

END
```

You'll be able to see different assumptions and filtering that is done. I can't say if your "query" is hitting these assumptions or is being filtered out, but this should give you some better insight into *why* it may not have shown up.

In the future I would use a resource such as Glenn Berry's Informational Diagnostics Scripts which are pre-written and work very well: https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-september-2014/